# Laravel cronjob to run at the minute xx:10 of every hour

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set a laravel cronjob, and all is fine except the time of execution.
I can see in the Laravel documentation many options such as daily, hourly .. etc, but I need to set it at the 10th minute of every hour.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
            $schedule->command('q:calc') 
                 ->hourly();


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `->cron('* * * * *')`

For example, the below code would be at minute 10

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('q:calc')->cron(10 * * * *);
}
```

Also this should do the same:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // Run the q:calc every hour at 10 mins past the hour
    $schedule->command('q:calc')->hourlyAt(10);
}
```

Further documentation can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

Comment: The second option should be  `->hourlyAt(10)`. `hourly()` doesn't take any arguments.